# View loaded from nib not getting touch event

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder, xib, user-interaction

I have created a custom keyboard, using some buttons. I created them using interface builder, and I create a `CustomKeyboardView` file..

So I have 3 files

1. CustomKeyboardView.h
2. CustomKeyboardView.m
3. CustomKeyboardView.xib

I am adding this view to my `UIViewController` like this

```
-(void)createCustomKeyboard{
    //kbdCustom is an instance of CustomKeyboardView
    kbdCustom       =  [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomKeyBoardView" 
                             owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    kbdCustom.delegate   =   self;
    CGRect frame         =   kbdCustom.frame;
    frame.origin.x       =   14.0;
    frame.origin.y       =   300.0;
    kbdCustom.frame      =   frame;
    kbdCustom.backgroundColor   =   [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview:kbdCustom];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:kbdCustom];
}
```

I am seeing the custom keyboard on my screen. But I couldn't touch in any of the button.

Nothing fancy in  `CustomKeyBoardView.m` file. I have some button handlers to address each different types of buttons in keyboard.

### CustomKeyboardView.m

```
@implementation CustomKeyBoardView
- (IBAction)numberPressed:(id)sender {
   NSLog(@"Number pressed");
}

- (IBAction)specialCharsPressed:(id)sender {
   NSLog(@"specialCharsPressed");
}

- (IBAction)clearTextPressed:(id)sender {
   NSLog(@"clearTextPressed");
}

- (IBAction)enterButtonPressed:(id)sender {
   NSLog(@"enterButtonPressed");
}
@end
```

Some other points that might help you (to help me)

1. I checked and rechecked the button handlers. They are wired to the
   `IBAction`.
2. I added a button programatically to the keyboard (Done it by
   overriding `awakeFromNib` function in `CustomKeyboardView.m`) and this
   button is also shown when I add it to `UIViewController`. But no
   userInteraction on that button too.
3. The `UIViewController` in question is shown in a
   `UIPopOverController`. And we use storyboard in our project.
4. I have done added some log to see whether user interaction is
   enabled in `kbdCustom` and its super view. Answer was in the
   affirmative

   ```
   NSLog(@"kbdCustom.userInteractionEnabled : %d"
      , kbdCustom.userInteractionEnabled);
   NSLog(@"superView.userInteractionEnabled : %d"
      , kbdCustom.superView.userInteractionEnabled);
   ```

   its output is

   ```
   kbdCustom.userInteractionEnabled : 1
   superView.userInteractionEnabled : 1
   ```
5. And off course, user interaction on all the button is `YES`, and all
   of them are enabled in interface builder.
6. I have adjusted the frame of the keyboard, to move it up over the
   UITextField( which is receiving touch events correctly). Now when I
   click on the keyboard buttons, the UITextField below it is getting
   touches, as if the keyboard is not there.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616576/a-view-loaded-from-the-nib-doesnt-receive-touch-events/10616667#10616667) question somewhat resembles this.. But I have no idea how the upvoted answer works.

Comment: I think the problem is in the frame (Origin x,y)

Comment: @Maulik I don't think so.. Since I am seeing the button on the scene correctly. Also I moved the keyboard to the top of the viewController's view (hiding the textfield which this keyboard populates) and when I click on the keyboard buttons, the textfield which is below the button getting the touch..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check for auto sizing of your view, and also set it's layer `clipsToBound`, then see if it's still visible. if not then that means your view have shrink to minimum size due to `autoSizing`, but it's subviews get displayed beyond the boundary of your `baseView`. In that case you can see them but can't touch.

Comment: You Sir are my hero.. It was the problem with xib autoresizing. For anyone who encounters this in the future, in `CustomKeyboardView.xib` in the size inspector pane, adjust the auto resizing settings.. Remove all red bars except top and left side.. Thanks

Comment: @Krishnabhadra At your service. :)

Comment: How to achieve same with autolayouts?

Comment: Ditto. Same issue but using auto layout and cannot get my xib to recognize touch events.